# Git Reset local repository after hard push to remote

Tags: git

We have a continuous integration build process pointed at a source git repository. When the process runs the CI process pushes its output into a releases repository. My question revolves around the following scenario.

1. Our CI server builds from source and pushes the results to our releases repository.
2. A developer checks out the releases repository, adds a schema change script (that isn't added by our CI process), then amends the previous commit and does a force push operation (in order to not add another commit as a result of just adding a script).
3. The next time the CI process runs and tries to push its output we get the following error "Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart."

What I would like to do is tell the CI server to reset the local repository match exactly the remote repo. I've looked at several similar problems and they all say to run the following commands (or very similar).

1. `git fetch --all`
2. `git reset --hard [remote repository]`

Even after running those commands prior to the build process, I still get the same error. Any ideas on what I should do? Or if what I want to do is even possible.

Comment: Try `git fetch` followed by `git reset --hard origin/branch`. That should work.

Comment: If fetch+reset doesn't work then that error is misleading and we will need more information about what it wants to know how to fix it

Comment: So it looks like I must have been somehow doing the reset wrong, I am updating my question with the answer, you were correct, the above did work

Comment: @matt.rothmeyer - Please don't add answers to questions. Just answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

So it seems that I was potentially resetting the wrong repository. I have changed the commands to do the following (with the last step potentially being unnecessary)

```
git fetch --all 
git reset --hard @{u}
git pull
```

The `@{u}` tells git to reset whatever branch is currently checked out, thus eliminating the need to specify the branch manually (which I must have been doing wrong).

One additional item of interest. If you are running the commands in a power shell script (how our CI server runs these actions) you have to write the git reset as follows (as the curly braces cause parse errors).

```
git reset --hard "@{u}"
```